# C++ Strange constructor behaviour

Tags: c++, constructor, stack, destructor

Can anybody explain to me the difference between **Complex a;** and **Complex b();**?

```
#include<iostream>

class Complex
{
public:

    Complex()
    {
        std::cout << "Complex Constructor 1" << std::endl;
    }

    Complex(float re, float im)
    {
        std::cout << "Complex Constructor 2" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Complex()
    {
        std::cout << "Complex Destructor" << std::endl;
    }    
};

int main()
{
    Complex a;
    std::cout << "--------------------------" << std::endl;
    Complex b();
    std::cout << "--------------------------" << std::endl;
    Complex c(0,0);
    std::cout << "--------------------------" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Complex Constructor 1
--------------------------
--------------------------
Complex Constructor 2
--------------------------
Complex Destructor
Complex Destructor
```

As you can see, **Complex a;** does call its default constructor, **Complex b();** doesn't and **Complex c(0,0);** calls an overloaded constructor.

What is going on here? I thought, that **Complex b();** would create a stack-variable and call it's default constructor to initialize it?

Answer (score 8):

`Complex b();` is function declaration. That is function taking no arguments and returning `Complex` object.

This is very common mistake and has its own name: [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

C++11 helped with this issue by introducing [uniform initialization syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Uniform_initialization)

```
Complex b{};
```

Comment: Hm, this looks like a design-weakness in C++, doesn't it?
I mean... I bet 9 out of 10 persons would expect this would call the constructor, like me ;-) Thx

Comment: @user1816771: It's something that reminds you to always be prepared. :)

Comment: I think it's just an ordinary vexing parse. The most vexing one is even more vexing.

Comment: @user1816771 forward function declaration are needed. Constructing objects is also needed. When they look the same - compiler has many choices - it might refuse to compile - or just choose one of them. To keep backward compatibility with C language - preferring function declaration was selected.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Excellent response. 
 It is important to know never to use parenthesis when instantiating an object because the C++ compiler has no way of differentiating this syntax with a function call; hence the existence of the phrase 'most vexing parse'. In this situation the compiler will assume a function call and rightfully so; as a developer, I couldn't even tell the difference at a glance.

Comment: @ThomasAnthony sometimes you have no choice: `std::vector` is an example: `std::vector<int> v(1,2);` is different than `std::vector v{1,2}`... First vector is `{1}`, second is `{1,2}`... You can use parenthesis when there is no possibility to treat it as function declaration....

Comment: @PiotrNycz I see, you have very valid point. I suppose I should retract my previous statement in favor of your own. You really got this one covered; 'nuff said.

Answer (score 4):

`Complex b();` declares a function that has no arguments and returns a `Complex`.